# Why is there premarket data for AAPL but not for GOOGL?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Just checked Google Finance to see the premarket for AAPL, and I can see that, but for GOOGL you don't get that information.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

There might not be any pre-market trades. Liquidity is significantly lower in the pre-market and it's common for many equities to not have any trades at all before regular market hours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Google Finance so I can't suggest a reason why it lacks today's pre-market trading.  However, GOOGL began trading this morning at 04:50:43 when 16 shares traded at $ 1,085.34

NASDAQ.com is a more reliable site.